# match patterns, but don't know how to replace them

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have string as

```
test\<string1\>again\<string2\>blabla
```

I set the regex pattern as below and tested with https://regex101.com/r/ZkIZvg/1

```
const regex = /\\<[^<]*\\\>/g
```

But how can I remove multiple `\<` and `\>` and get this string

```
test<string1>again<string2>blabla
```

So `string1` and `string2` need be kept as same.

I can't simply replace `\<` and `\>`, because I will only replace them, when they are paired, and I don't know how many pairs will be in string, maybe 1, 2, 3 or more pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the text between the `<`s, and replace with that captured group:

```js
const input = String.raw`test\<string1\>again\<string2\>blabla`;
console.log(
  input.replace(/\\(<[^<]*)\\\>/g, '$1>')
);
```

Comment: So simple, amazing.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Relace backSlash with the empty string
const str = "test\<string1\>again\<string2\>blabla";
console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, ''));
```